# Mongoose: configuring user settings route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a PUT route which allows a User to change their `nativelanguage` from the `default: English` but seem to be running into a few problems. I've successfully written PUT routes for other models, but it seems that the User one is acting differently.

This route :

```
router.put('/settings/:id/nativelanguage', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    var nativeLanguage = req.body.nativeLanguage;
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {nativeLanguage}, function (err, updatedUser){
        if (err){
            res.send("error... ruh roh");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/dashboard"); 
            console.log(updatedUser)
        }
    });
});
```

This form :

```
<div class="nativelanguage">
            <form action="/user/<%=User._id%>/nativelanguage?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                <select name="nativeLanguage">
              <option value="English">English</option>
              <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
              <option value="French">French</option>
              <option value="German">German</option>
              <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
              <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
              <option value="Polish">Polish</option>

            </select>
              <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
            </form>
```

Give this error:

```
Cannot PUT /user//nativelanguage
```

And with a route as so `/user/nativelanguage/:id` the user ID still doesn't show in the URL for some reason.

---

And I have `bodyParser`, `sessions` and `methodOverride` set up. I'm stumped, because this exact configuration works for a `Posts` collection. Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: HTML standard doesn't allow forms to send PUT request.  Also is the action url correct? Shouldn't it be "/settings/user._id/nativelanguage"?

Comment: `methodOverride` is able to override that HTML standard. Action URL is using view engine `ejs` to put the `userId` in from the logged in user and requires those tags `<% %>`